# PWM signal through a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pwm, switching

So there are many topics on using a MOSFET to generate a PWM signal, but what I am trying to do is to use a MOSFET to act as a switch to open and close a channel that my PWM signal is travelling on. I attempted this and when I apply my PWM signal to S and open the gate, my output on D is an analog high signal. Insight on how to get a PWM signal to flow across SD would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to do is create an analog switch, but why? If your PWM signal is digital then it will probably be easier to use a logic gate. What is the source of the PWM signal, and what are you sending it to?

Comment: Correct, but i cant seem to find such a gate. The source of the signal is a MCU and the load is a LED driver.

Comment: You could use a tri-state buffer such as 74HC1G125, or if you can change the MCU source code then just set the I/O pin to input mode to disconnect the PWM.

Comment: @OrienWalker Please do the following, 1)Draw a schematic with the tool (button above quesiton box) 2) Write a clear specific question 3) See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Insight on how to get a PWM signal to flow across SD would be greatly
> appreciated

The first battle is keeping the MOSFET turned on when source is dancing up and down due to the input signal - you have to ensure that the gate voltage is significantly higher than the maximum voltage at the source or the MOSFET may start to switch off.

The second (and harder) battle is keeping the MOSFET turned off when you don't want a signal to pass. I'm assuming an N channel device in this answer.

If the source input is a PWM signal (say between 0 V and 5 V) then you have to ensure that the gate (off) signal is the same as (or more negative than) the source signal.

> I attempted this and when i apply my PWM signal to S and open the gate

No, an open circuit gate is a bad idea - it will float to some value (because it is very high impedance) and either turn on the MOSFET or cause some manner of feedthrough from source to drain.

Tie gate to 0V to turn it off but, then you have the problem of the internal parasitic diode inside an NFET: -

[image]

It's hard to find an NFET (or PFET) without one.

So my recommendation is use an analogue switch (simplified diagram): -

[image]

This overcomes the body diode problem because the "body" isn't joined to the source.

Comment: SO to clarify, I tested this theory with a PFET. So in your first point, if i understand you correctly, i need to make my activation signal going to Gate higher than the peak of my PWM signal? The second point, having the gate tied to GND when turned off, I have that done already. Also could you elaborate more on this last diagram and the solution you suggest? I am unclear as to what it means.

Comment: Realistically you should consider using an integrated analogue switch because you will not get the performance using a single mosfet.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of one?

Comment: Try maxim, Texas instruments or analo devices. An example is the CD4066 off the top of my head.

Comment: The standard way for thanks is to accept formally the answer. I don't think there will be any more answers but it's usually best waiting a day before accepting . Anyway, good luck.